# Ubuntu Won't Boot From USB On My PC

Tags: boot, asus

I have a PC with an ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING motherboard and I can't get Ubuntu to work for me. I have 2 GTX 970s in my pc. When I try boot Ubuntu from a USB stick it just either hangs on a black screen or shows graphical glitches and hangs on the console screen before it even makes it to the GUI. I've used Rufus to create the bootable USB and tried both UEFI and non UEFI. 14.04 is the only one that will boot and it still doesn't work right. The screen is stretched vertically and I can only see the top half.

I need it to work to run a python script for an xbox one hdd. I don't mind having it installed on my pc as a dual boot since Linux always comes in handy.

Sorry if this is a stupid easy thing I'm just missing. It worked fine on my laptop when j had it installed but I need it on the pc for the extra SATA connections.

Comment: See [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). Alternatively, you can install ubuntu in VirtualBox and then allow it to access your Xbox HDD  with whole disk passthrough.  If you have a USB to SATA adapter, it's even easier. Maybe that python script can be run in Windows too ?

Comment: I think you have problems with the driver for the nvidia graphics cards. Did you try with the **boot option `nomodeset`** according to this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. The script basically is supposed to just create the partitions and the GUID. That's basically all I need to do but they recommended Ubuntu.

Comment: If you can make Ubuntu run from the USB stick, it is an alternative to install your python script into it and do the job. The basic Ubuntu system on a USB stick is live-only, which means that the python script will be gone after shutdown or reboot. That is OK, if you want to use the script only once, but if you want to do it many times, you can create a **persistent live** system using **mkusb**. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb. Then the installed python script (and other installed programs) can persist (survive shutdown and  reboot).